# Configure project path for node-inspector

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I am running a node project with yarn and gulp build scripts.

The tasks are monitored by nodemon. The Configuration in the `gulpfile.babel.js` is:

```
  plugins.nodemon({
    script: path.join('dist', 'index.js'),
    ext: 'js',
    exec: 'node-inspector & node --debug',
    ignore: ['node_modules/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['copy', 'babel']
  })
```

this works all fine. The only problem is that node-inspector can not load. It just displays the error:

```
Network.loadResourceForFrontend failed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/me/server/controllers/user.controller.js'
```

The path `/home/me/server/controllers/user.controller.js` is wrong. The real path would be `/home/me/projects/test-project/dist/server/controllers/user.controller.js`

Where can I configure the project base path for node-inspector?

Answer (score 0):

use the absolute path __dirname

```
plugins.nodemon({
    script: path.join(__dirname, './dist/index.js'),
    ext: 'js',
    exec: 'node-inspector & node --debug',
    ignore: ['node_modules/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['copy', 'babel']
})
```

Comment: This leads into the right direction. However, it doesn't solve the issue. Looks like the path in the source maps introduces the problem. The source map lies next to the `.js` file in `dist/server/controllers`. In the sourcemap file, I see the following which references the wrong source location: `{"version":3,"sources":["server/controllers/user.controller.js"],`.